# How to fast locate bad data in a select query using cast function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL Server database, there is a varchar column `begintime` which has  value like `2023/07/10` in table t1.

I use

```
select cast(begintime as date) from t1
```

to convert it to date and it return error message said some data can't be converted.
After checking all values in the table finally I found the reason. Some data 's length is 12 instead of 10,with a return and blank character in the end.I wonder is there some tools in sql server studio which can fast locate the bad data? Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Why didn't you create the column as `date` to begin with?  Solve the problem once, when you insert a record, then never again.

Comment: Have you tried using ``FORMAT`` to add leading zeros? Like Tim said, or you could format the columns as dates to avoid any problems in the future.

Comment: @Tim RobertsI know.But  actually this is not my db and I can only query data from it.

Comment: It must be something else. `cast('2023/7/10' as date)` does not result in error

Comment: Look at the MDSN on CAST and CONVERT. This is 101 stuff.

Comment: Can you show us a sample error?

Comment: depending on his local date settings, yyyy/m/dd won't be parsed correctly. i would probably use substrings and datefromparts to create the date instead of relying on finicky CONVERT here

Comment: @siggemannen - under what date setting will `yyyy/m/dd` be parsed differently than `yyyy/mm/dd`?

Comment: @MartinSmith, hmm, i was thinking where you have day and month flipped perhaps, but it was kind of a speculation, i don't trust anything other than YYYYMMDD for automatic conversion myself. Substringing at least would avoid those errors

Comment: @siggemannen - I don't see any setting where this happens https://dbfiddle.uk/c5qOnf0w

Comment: @MartinSmith, ya, you're right, i extended your check a bit: https://dbfiddle.uk/nxa9U4kd even 7/30 succeeds. So probably OP has some non-dates in the field?

Comment: or perhaps he stores yyyy/d/m ?

Comment: Thanks all. I found the reason,it's because a return character in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `CAST` or `CONVERT` built in functions to make `2023/7/10` as `2023/07/10`

```
select CAST('2023/7/10' as date);
select CONVERT(date ,'2023/7/10');
```

above line's gives out put if date is valid to convert else gives error response.

you may use `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT` this will give you out put if date is valid to convert else return `NULL`

```
select TRY_CAST('2023/17/10' as date); -- returns NULL
select TRY_CAST('2023/7/10' as date); -- returns 2023-07-10
select TRY_CONVERT(date ,'2023/27/10'); -- returns NULL
select TRY_CONVERT(date ,'2023/7/10'); -- returns 2023-07-10
```